# Vertical scaling for query performance

Tags: mysql

Some advice would be great.

If I have a 10TB unpartitioned table in MYSQL and want to ETL it into a new table which is partitioned.

Will vertically scaling to a huge server help? Will performance increase much?

Comment: **ETL** means **Extract, Transform and Load**.

Comment: The answer depends on how you are coding this. More can probably be gained from horizontal scaling, and running multiple ETL processes.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to answer it accurately. It depends on whether the ETL is currently waiting for I/O or waiting for CPU. If it's waiting on I/O, then scaling up the server to "huge" probably isn't going to help. But it also depends on what "huge" means to you.

Comment: Run your horses. What's the bottleneck on the ETL? Logic/CPU, read I/O, write I/O, RAM usage, other?

Comment: Based on what you have said, I expect you go get zero benefits from the exercise.  If you would like to discuss it further, please show us the schema and the main queries involved in the ETL.